# Ext of a zero dimensional sheaf on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective algebraic $K3$ surface over the field of complex numbers and let $E$ be a sheaf supported on a finite set,then my question is the following:

Is it true that $Ext^{i}(E, \mathcal O_X) =0 $ for $i=0,1$?

Does it have something to do with $E$ being zero dimensional and hence a flasque sheaf?

Can someone give me any hint?(or may be a reference)

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Use Serre duality.

Comment: Thank  you very much @Sasha, for your comment.I have now by Serre duality $Ext^{i}(E, w_X) \cong (H^{2-i}(X,E))^*$, where the right hand side vector space is zero for $i \leq 1$ as $E$ is zero dimensional and hence a flasque sheaf.This means $Ext^{i}(E, w_X) =0$ for $i=0,1$.Also since I am working on $K3$ surface(which I will edit in my question) I have desired result